# Custom password field in not visible in browser

Tags: html, css, visibility, passwordbox, cross-browser

I want to make custom password in HTML But when i am running it with browser like chrome , Mozilla its not visible there.Please find my HTML & CSS.What wrong i am doing?

```
<link href="mypwd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input type="password" class="pwd">
```

CSS File:

```
.pwd{

    border: 3px;
    border-color: red;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there, you just haven't defined a proper border.

Try this:

```
.pwd {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Or if you'd rather not use shorthand:

```
.pwd {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<link>` will have to be in the `<head>` as far as I know.

Also border should be:

```
border: 3px solid red;
```

Comment: It's not valid HTML, but most browsers will still process it.

Comment: I kept CSS link in <Head> itself.But in eclipse when i open this HTML with open with -> Web Page Editor ,in Preview password field is not showing.Whats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to

```
.pwd{
    border : 3px solid red;
}
```

For more infor check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPTwJ/2/)